# PHP - Ensure array contains specific keys

Tags: php, arrays

I have a PHP array like this..

```
Array
(
    [04] => 1
    [09] => 1
    [10] => 1
    [01] => 1
)
```

I want to make sure that it has keys 1-10 in it, if they do not exist then I want them to be added with a value of 0, so my final array looks like this..

```
Array
(
    [01] => 1
    [02] => 0
    [03] => 0
    [04] => 1
    [05] => 0
    [06] => 0
    [07] => 0
    [08] => 0
    [09] => 1
    [10] => 1
)
```

I am doing it like this..

```
if (!array_key_exists("01",$myarray)) {
     $myarray['01'] = 0;
}

if (!array_key_exists("02",$myarray)) {
     $myarray['02'] = 0;
}

if (!array_key_exists("02",$myarray)) {
     $myarray['02'] = 0;
}

if (!array_key_exists("03",$myarray)) {
     $myarray['03'] = 0;
}
```

And so on up until 10, then I do a ksort to get them in the right order

```
ksort($myarray)
```

This works but I am aware this is quite clunky and probably not very efficient.

Can anyone point me towards a better solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using functional techniques ends up making your process look convoluted.  An important factor in choosing the right solution should be the omission of the `ksort()` call.  If a coding solution is engineered properly, you store the data in the desired order to begin with -- no mopping up after iterating.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/kYHY6))

```
$data = ["04" => 1, "09" => 1, "10" => 1, "01" => 1];

for ($x = 1; $x < 11; ++$x) {
    $key = sprintf("%02d", $x);  // ensure proper padding with 0
    $result[$key] = $data[$key] ?? 0;  // null coalescing operator from php5.6+
}

print_r($result);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [01] => 1
    [02] => 0
    [03] => 0
    [04] => 1
    [05] => 0
    [06] => 0
    [07] => 0
    [08] => 0
    [09] => 1
    [10] => 1
)
```

Answer (score 3):

Just use a for loop like this

```
    For($i = 1;$i<=10;$i++){

        $index = (string)sprintf("%02d",$i);

        if (!array_key_exists($index,$myarray)) {
            $myarray[$index] = 0;
        }

    }
```

i hope it help.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a simple `for` loop :

```
$myarray = array(
    1 => 1, 
    2 => 1,
    3 => 1);

for ($i = 1; $i < 11; $i++) {
    if (!isset($myarray[$i]))
        $myarray[$i] = 0;
}

print_r($myarray);

/* Output : 

Array ( [1] => 1 [2] => 1 [3] => 1 [4] => 0 
[5] => 0 [6] => 0 [7] => 0 [8] => 0 [9] => 0 [10] => 0 )

*/
```

Answer (score 1):

You could build a blank array (using [`array_fill()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-fill.php)) and then use [`array_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-replace.php) to overwrite the blanks with the values your after...

```
$myarray = array(
    4 => 1,
    9 => 1,
    10 => 1,
    1 => 1
);

$blank = array_fill(1, 10, 0);
$result = array_replace ($blank, $myarray);

print_r($result);
```

Which outputs...

```
Array
(
    [1] => 1
    [2] => 0
    [3] => 0
    [4] => 1
    [5] => 0
    [6] => 0
    [7] => 0
    [8] => 0
    [9] => 1
    [10] => 1
)
```

Answer (score 1):

**try this simple thing**

```
    $array=Array
            (
                [04] => 1
                [09] => 1
                [10] => 1
                [01] => 1
            );

    $myarray=Array
            (
                [01] => 0
                [02] => 0
                [03] => 0
                [04] => 0
                [05] => 0
                [06] => 0
                [07] => 0
                [08] => 0
                [09] => 0
                [10] => 0
            );

    foreach ($array as $key => $value){
        $myarray[$key]=$value;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You might use [array_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-replace.php) and [array_fill_keys](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-fill-keys.php) to create a prefilled array with a leading zero for your keys and 0 as the value:

```
$result = array_replace(
    array_fill_keys(["01", "02", "03", "04", "05", "06", "07", "08", "09", "10"], 0),
    ["04" => 1, "09" => 1, "10" => 1, "01" => 1]
    );
print_r($result)
```

That would give you:

```
Array
(
    [01] => 1
    [02] => 0
    [03] => 0
    [04] => 1
    [05] => 0
    [06] => 0
    [07] => 0
    [08] => 0
    [09] => 1
    [10] => 1
)
```

You could also use a range to create the array with your keys:

```
$result = array_replace(
    array_fill_keys(
        array_map(
            function ($x) {
                return sprintf("%02d", $x);
            },
            range(1, 10, 1)
        ), 0), ["04" => 1, "09" => 1, "10" => 1, "01" => 1]);

print_r($result);
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/SunLO)